# UnboundLocalError in nested functions

Tags: python

I use the following code to experiment with **nonlocal**

```
def a():
    b = 5
    print(f"b (1) = {b}")
    def c():
        #nonlocal b
        print(f"b (2) = {b}")
        b = 3
    c()

a()
```

When I comment out nonlocal I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in a
  File "<string>", line 6, in c
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'b' where it is not associated with a value
```

I expected the value of variable b from function a to be printed out on the console and then a locale variable of the same name would be created. But obviously when the function is parsed, it is noted that there is a local variable called b in the function c, but it is not yet assigned a value, as this is done at runtime.
Are my thoughts correct and are there sources where I can read more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup , you're correct When you comment out the `nonlocal` statement, Python treats `b` as a local variable inside function `c()`. Therefore, trying to access it before assigning a value results in an `UnboundLocalError`.
If you want to modify the variable `b` defined in the outer scope within the inner function `c()`, you need to use the `nonlocal` keyword.

but you can also  achieve your desired output without `nonlocal`, just by passing the variable `b` as an argument to the inner function `c()`.his way, you're  providing the value of `b` to the inner function and avoiding the scope-related issues.

```
def a():
    b = 5
    print(f"b (1) = {b}")
    
    def c(b):  
        print(f"b (2) = {b}")
        b = 3
    
    c(b)  

a()
```